# How to delete the single instance of recurring event in android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar, recurring-events

I am developing app which will show the list of user calendar events. I am able to add, edit and delete the event but I want to delete the single instance of recurring event.
I am not able to succeed trying different methods and suggestions after googling.

Any code example and guide will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?